# The strcat() function in C changes a random variable in my program?

Tags: c, strcat

Here is the code I wrote:

```
int main(void){

  int m = 8;
  char digits[] = {};

  printf("%d\n" , m);
  strcat(digits, "0");
  printf("%d\n" , m);
}
```

I would expect the variable m to be unchanged but the output is this:

```
8
0
```

Why does this happen? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You just discovered first-hand what a buffer overflow attack is :)

Comment: Just what do you think `char digits[] = {};` allocates?

Comment: @Alexander There comes a point in any engineering process where the person doing the work has to know what is proper, with no safety net.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's even simpler than that, *"C does not come with Training-Wheels..."* (but it does come with ample *Compiler Warnings*...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't disagree. But that's not obvious to new-comers, and it doesn't meet there expectations. Be nice.

Comment: Saving the code with headers `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>` too, and compiling with `gcc -O3   -g         -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes        -pedantic za37.c -o za37` yields the errors (because of `-Werror` and `-pedantic`): 
`za37.c:7:19: error: use of GNU empty initializer extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-empty-initializer]` —
  `char digits[] = {};` —
`za37.c:7:19: error: zero size arrays are an extension [-Werror,-Wzero-length-array]`

Comment: C is a low-level, literal language. There's very little that it does for you automatically like what more modern languages do for you. Thus, `char digits[] = {};` defines `digits` for you as requested, and allocates no space to it, as requested. It's only "non-intuitive" if you're only used to the higher level languages.

Answer (score 4):

Your array 'digits' is not allocated any memory and has size of zero. When you treat it execute 'strcat', C tries to do *something* using the address of your variable, overflows, and puts stuff into memory *next* to your variable's location.

Take a look at the malloc function, here's a link explaining it. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm

Comment: Note that standard C, as opposed to GCC C (for example), does not allow arrays of size zero.  The code shown is strictly just erroneous — there is no defined meaning for the `char digits[] = {};` construct.